# How does blocking port 25 prevent spam (but not 587)?

Tags: email, smtp

It is common practice for ISPs and cloud providers to block outgoing traffic on port 25.

I understand this is to prevent spam; e.g. a person could launch an Amazon EC2 instance, and send a million emails.

But for example, port 587 can be used to send email as well, and it is not commonly blocked.  So why can't a person send a million emails through port 587?

Basically, I'm asking, what is special about port 25 that makes it more prone to abuse than 587?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right it does not completely prevent spam, but **from a business perspective what matters** for the cloud provider is something slightly different than trying to *prevent all spam*.

Cloud hosters do not have strong incentives not to take money from spammers. The thing that hurts them **is being the owner of the IP space the spam is delivered from.** They do not want to be *that cloud hoster everyone blocklists*. That would be a less useful & thus less profitable *cloud hoster*!

For spammers, these are just two paths to the **same** goal:

1. abusing some random companies cloud servers to send spam via port 25, potentially directly to the victim
2. abusing some random companies mail (service provider) credentials to send spam via an *authenticated smtp session* on port 587, relayed by some other party

But for the *cloud hoster*, there is a **huge difference**:

1. in option 1, the complaints and mitigations are directed at the company providing the server, the *cloud hoster*
2. while in option 2 people will blame & take action against the person having their smtp credentials compromised and/or the last relay that accepted the compromised credentials. The *cloud hoster* does not lose (as much) credibility&reputation in that case.

Someone spamming port 25 is someone I can put on a blocklist. If the cloud hoster recycles network addresses quickly, my mitigation will cause collateral damage for his next customer, and thus for him.

If someone is spamming me via abused smtp logins on port 587, his spam will enter my systems mixed with other, clean mail. I can less effectively use network-level blocking there - and if I do, I will more likely target a later relaying party.

Answer (score 4):

TCP port 587 is used for authenticated SMTP access (with TLS) for client applications or devices; this is useless for spammers, whose need to send spoofed messages really doesn't go hand-in-hand with enforced authentication.

Comment: One can send spam without spoofing though, and a domain can be purchased for $0.99

Comment: True, but that's not what spammers do; they spoof sender addresses and (try to) relay their messages through third-party mail servers. If the sender address, domain and IP address were fixed, blocking spam would be trivially easy.

Answer (score 1):

This question is off-topic for this forum: Business environments don’t suffer from this issue.

But in short: the block isn’t there to prevent you from sending email at all, but to prevent people from setting up potentially misconfigured mail servers: If server-to-server traffic is blocked, the adverse effect of an open relay is negligible.

Comment: What is the potential harm of a misconfigured mail server?

Comment: Allowing someone else to relay messages through it.

Comment: Maybe your business environment doesn't include mail servers, but many others do!

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I misunderstood your post. Where I live, ISPs limit residential connections (but provide their own authenticated mail relay hosts), but if you purchase a business connection (even one directed at SMBs), you get a real, open Internet connection. I expected this to be true pretty much everywhere.

Comment: That happens here as well. But port 25 is also blocked on virtually every cloud provider, where businesses deploy applications, and which the OP explicitly gave as an example.